# How can I check if a string exists in any file within a directory / subdirectory?

Tags: python, bash, directory

I have a list of strings and I would like to print out any that are not present within a file in a directory. (I don't want to check the headers)

I understand how to loop through the list, but have been unable to find out how to search within all files of a directory.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
import fnmatch
import os

matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('BrowserClient'):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'file.png'):
    print filename
```

This only searches filenames and I want to instead search through every file in the directory and sub directory.

Comment: In case you just wanted to find a string in a set of files as a standalone problem you can use "grep".

Comment: nb: `grep` is a commandline tool on all Unix (so also OS X) computers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [**`open`**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) the file:

```
import fnmatch
import os

targets = ['Hello', 'World', 'Foo', 'Bar']
matches = []
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('BrowserClient'):
  for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, 'file.png'):
    for word in open(filename, 'r').read().split():
      for item in target:
        if word == item:
          matches.append([filename, item])
```

Comment: Take care with the size of your files. Doing open(...).read() may cause you problems if there are some huge files to be read.